# Is there any way to crop widgets in HTC Sense?

Tags: htc-sense, htc-droid-incredible, app-widgets

I've seen people crop off part of a widget to make it take up less space.  Is there any readily-available way to do this on an HTC phone with Sense (Droid Incredible, to be specific)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you purchase the paid version of launcher pro you can crop widgets. Just long press on a widget with Launcher Pro installed and running, and then let go. It should be highlighted in an off orange/yellow color. In the lower right corner is a little arrow type icon, click this and drag to crop the widget.

Not sure how to do this otherwise.

Comment: The downside is you can't do use Sense widgets in Launcher Pro (AFAIK)

Comment: True but for most HTC widgets there are alternatives that give almost the same functionality. I just wish HTC would buy out the Launcher Pro team so we had a choice of launcher and both would work with widgets. That would be sweet!

Comment: If I decide I don't like Launcher Pro, will I be able to uninstall it and get my Sense UI and widgets back?

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't clear defaults or cache for Sense you should lose anything. think of launchers as another desktop that will run on top of Sense. In fact I also recommend downloading Home Switcher as well. That way you can easily go back and forth till you decide which one you like better.

Comment: FYI: In the unpaid version of Launcher Pro you can resize widgets when you add them.

Comment: I don't get that option. I just added a widget and nothing happened except the widget it's now on my homescreen.

Comment: @Webs: Long-click on the widget.  It should turn yellow and show a little drag tab in the bottom right.  (Then, if you have the free version, you get a nice annoying message about how that feature is only available in the paid version)

Comment: Yea I know how to resize them, read my answer you were commenting on. But Joe said this could be done with the unpaid version.